# Unlocking CRM 2011 Field with JavaScript only if creating new contact/account

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, contacts, account

I know there's JavaScript to unlock a field in CRM 2011, but I only want to unlock those fields on 'new' account and contact forms.  Existing contacts/accounts should always have locked fields.  The reason for this is because we will be having integration set up with another system, but if a rep needs to manually enter a new contact/account, we want them to have that ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for the [Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_getFormType).

In your case you'll check if the current FormType equals 1 (Create):

```
onLoad: function () {
    var ft = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();

    if (ft === 1) {
        // unlock your attributes here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Filburt. That's exactly what I needed.  I used the following code under the onload section:

```
{
var ft = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
if (ft == 1) 
{
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_universalid").setDisabled(true); 
} 
}
```